# hosting a site using apache at home

Tags: php, mysql, apache-2.2, hosting

Is it possible to host my site using my own PC via Apache server to make it online? if yes, can anyone please guide me on how to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is *the most asked question on server fault*. To see a list of duplicates, please go to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9686/what-is-the-most-rampant-duplicate-on-stack-overflow/50116#50116

Answer (score 1):

- First, get it working on your computer - so, download and install Apache and get it running, and when you can browse to http://localhost/ and see your site that's good.
- Second, get that visible to the outside world, and that depends on your connection. It normally means forwarding a port in from your router, and how to do it depends on what kind of connection (ADSL, Cable, etc) and what make/model of router, but you tell it to pass TCP Port 80 from External connections to the internal IP address of your computer.

Then go to http://checkip.dyndns.org and find your external IP address, and browse from another computer to http://{your-external-ip} and see your site.

When you have got that working, there are some more improvements which can be done to make it more usable.

Which Operating system do you have? (Windows? Windows XP? Windows 7? Linux? Mac OS X?) and what kind of internet connection?